# Run a job with (Spring @Scheduled) on specific days

Tags: java, spring, schedule

I have a customer check job. I could not find how to automatically set the job time to run on 10am only on Monday, Friday and Saturday. Is there a possible way to set it using Spring `@Scheduled`?

Comment: I would recommend quartz-scheduler. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * MON,FRI,SAT")
public void dailyScheduleJob() {
    /*
    your code here
    */
}
```

Additionally, if the requested days are sequential such as Monday to Friday(a job running only on weekdays), this expression is shorter:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * MON-FRI")
public void dailyScheduleJob() {
    /*
    your code here
    */
}
```

It is also possible to represent days with numbers from **1-7**.
In this case 1 will be SUN, and 7 will be SAT and the same cron job above can be written like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * 2-6")
public void dailyScheduleJob() {
    /*
    your code here
    */
}
```